# Handling error for individual items in webview

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-webview

I have a webview which loads an offline HTML . My offline HTML contains

- Text
- Local Images
- Embedded videos

All works fine but when user doesn't have the internet connection the 'text' and 'images' load fine but 'embedded videos' part shows an ugly NO INTERNET CONNECTION error.

My question is how do I handle this error and replace it with my own custom error.

I want to keep showing all the other contents in my html even if there is no internet connection but replace embedded video error message with custom error message.

Anyone knows how to achieve this? 
Cheers

My webview code

```
webView.ClearCache(true);

webView.ClearHistory();

string HTML_DATA = "";

if (File.Exists(localPath))

{

string HTML_LOCAL = File.ReadAllText(localPath);


HTML_DATA =  HTML_LOCAL;

}


webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

webView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;

webView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;

webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass()); 

webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", HTML_DATA, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Now the results are the following

> **With internet**

[image]

> **Without internet**

[image]

Comment: Show your code and error logs instead of writing text only. That would help to understand issue more easily

Comment: Are you using Xamarin?  and what tag did you use for embedded video? Share code for better understanding.

Comment: Updated with code and screenshots

Comment: and yes i am using xamarin but Java solution is also acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is how do I handle this error and replace it with my own custom error.

You can handle it in WebViewClient like codes below, but it will replace the whole page of WebView with your error page:

```
public class MyClient:WebViewClient
{
    public Context _context;
    public MyClient(Context c)
    {
        _context = c;
    }
    public override void OnReceivedError(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error)
    {
        base.OnReceivedError(view, request, error);
        var errMsg = error.DescriptionFormatted;
        Toast.MakeText(_context, errMsg, ToastLength.Long).Show();

        string htmlData = $"<html><body><div align='center'>This is the description for the load fail : {errMsg}</div></body>";

        view.LoadUrl("about:blank");
        view.LoadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
        view.Invalidate();
    }

   ...
```

Alternatively, you can handle the error in Html, you can define an error window with the same size of your webview, and hide/show it according to the internet states:

```
<DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
        <iframe id="mFrame" width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/a5GMRrEJaVo" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div id="errorWindow" width="854" height="480">
            This is the div for your custom error view
        </div>
<script>
    (function(){
        "use strict"

        var mIframe=document.getElementById("mFrame");
        var errorWindow=document.getElementById("errorWindow");

        if(navigator.onLine)
        {
            //internet available
            mIframe.hidden=false;
            errorWindow.hidden=true;
        }else
        {
            //internet not available
            mIframe.hidden=true;
            errorWindow.hidden=false;
        }

    })()
</script>
</body>
```

Notes: you will have to define following permission to have `navigator.onLine` work:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the alternate method, works sort of, but for iFrames i can use HAP to add the ID for iframes but I also have other contents such as IMGs and some cases the DIVs, this is making it difficult to handle each and every possible tag which requires internet to be displayed. Is there any other way? Like, i can just somehow identify the Error on page and only replace that section on page for the whole page?

Comment: I don't see any other approach to do that. Communication between Html side and C# side is very limited.